# What's the purpose of SQL keyword “AS”?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am wondering about what `AS` Keyword do in SQL Server.

I know it's context when it is used on a query that it sets up an alias, however, I do not know what it means when it's used in stored procedures or User Defined Functions. Why is it needed before the begin keyword?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.UDF_rangeoddeven( @start int, @end int, @oddeven nvarchar(4)) 
returns @table table
(
    Number int 
) 
AS
BEGIN
    IF @oddeven = 'even'
        WHILE @start <= @end
            BEGIN
                IF @start%2 = 0
                    BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO @table
                    SELECT @start;
                    END
                SET @start = @start + 1; 
            END
    ELSE
        WHILE @start <= @end
            BEGIN
                IF @start%2 = 1
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO @table
                    SELECT @start;
                END
                SET @start = @start + 1;
            END
    RETURN
END
GO
```

Comment: It simply marks the start of the procedure. Similar to `create view ... AS select ...` and I think you can create a procedure without using `begin`

Comment: It,s Syntax just it and the reason don,t matter i think .

Comment: Lots of the T-SQL language design happened *decades* ago. It's just "how it is", there's no "fundamental" reason behind it.

Comment: Because that's how the language was designed.

Comment: I could *guess* that it's there to more easily switch the parser from "header" parsing for options to the general T-SQL parser for statements. A lot of the early T-SQL language design seemed to be oriented around making it easier on the parser.

Comment: As part of SQL grammar, this instructs the SQL Engine to translate whatever follows this keyword as a definition in case of SQL objects such as procedures/functions/triggers and in case of columns, this instructs SQL Engine to treat the value which follows this keyword as an alias

Answer (score 1):

It's a hunk of language syntax.

For stored functions / procedures (sps), common table expressions (CTEs), and views,  `AS` works as part of the declaration syntax.   Think of it this way: *declare public_part AS private part*.

The public part of an sp is its declaration: how to access it. The private part is the code.  The same is true of a CTE:

```
WITH summary AS (
   SELECT id, MAX(val) maxval, MIN(val) minval, SUM(val) sumval
     FROM raw
    GROUP BY ID
)
```

The grammar is reversed from the way it's used in SELECTs, in which it's *declare expression AS name.*

Why is it reversed?  Maybe Dr. Stonebraker or Dr. Date know?

Some SQL dialects allow `AS` to be omitted in some contexts.